# Arrays and For Loops: Creating a list of numbers Greatest to Least

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int greatestToLeastPancakeAmount[10] = {};
    int greatestToLeastPersonNumber[10] = {};
    int pancakeAmount;
    int x;
    cout << "Pancake Glutton 1.0 \n\n"; //State program's title
    cout << "10 Different people ate pancakes for breakfast.. \n\n";
    x = 0;
    for(x=0;x<10;x++) {
        cout << "How many pancakes did person " << (x + 1) << " eat? > ";
        cin >> pancakeAmount;
        greatestToLeastPersonNumber[x] = (x + 1);
        greatestToLeastPancakeAmount[x] = pancakeAmount;
        /*while(pancakeAmount > greatestToLeastPancakeAmount[(x - 1)]) {
            int storeGreatestToLeastPancakeAmount = greatestToLeastPancakeAmount[(x-1)];
            int storeGreatestToLeastPersonNumber = greatestToLeastPersonNumber[(x-1)];
            greatestToLeastPancakeAmount[(x-1)] = pancakeAmount;
            greatestToLeastPersonNumber[(x-1)] = x;
            greatestToLeastPancakeAmount[x] = storeGreatestToLeastPancakeAmount;
            greatestToLeastPersonNumber[x] = storeGreatestToLeastPersonNumber;
        }*/
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
    for(x=0;x<10;x++) {
        cout << "Person " << greatestToLeastPersonNumber[x] << " ate " << greatestToLeastPancakeAmount[x] << " pancakes!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do I accomplish outputting the number of people that ate the most pancakes followed by the people that at the least amount of pancakes?

Comment: There's a `std::minmax` algorithm.

Comment: That's like telling someone that doesn't know how to fish to use a fishing pole and expect them to catch a fish..

Comment: Well, reference pages such as [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) generally include usage examples as well as information on the parameters etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the general requirement: You **always** need to verify after reading that you successfully read whatever you tried to read, e.g.:

```
if (!(std::cin >> greatestToLeastPancakeAmount[x])) {
    std::cout << "failed to read number of pancakes (ignoring this line)\n";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Next, there isn't really a need to store any identifier for the persons:

1. It isn't needed.
2. The stored identifier is always `i + 1` where `i` is index anyway.

With your setup the easiest approach to compute the number of persons who ate the most or least amount of pancakes is probably to `std::sort()` the array and then count the number of equal counts at the start and the end of the array. An easier approach entirely is, however, to just stick increment a value in a `std::map<int, int>` and then output the first and the last element of the map:

```
std::map<int, int> count;
for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
    ++count[greatestToLeastPancakeAmount[i]];
}
if (count.empty()) { // won't happen until you start tracking the number of people entered
    std::cout << "nobody ate any pancake\n";
}
else {
    std::cout << (--count.end())->second << " persons ate " << (--count.end())->first
              << " pancakes\n";
    std::cout << count.begin()->second << " persons ate " << count.begin()->first
              << " pancakes\n";
}
```